# Configure systemd to gracefully restart when memory is almost full

Tags: mariadb, memory

I changed my database to another server, same settings, everything equal, but it seems this new server the memory usage is always close to 100% in less than 2 days (128GB RAM) and I can't upgrade it right now.

I have been doing manual restarts when it's gets close to full but there is a way to do gracefully do this with `systemd`?

OOM is killing the database when that happens. Do you think my specs are too bad? The applications accessing it have a 7ms latency.

What would be the best way to deal with this with `systemd` or other means till I can upgrade my RAM? Is there other trick I can use to buy time?

Memory is leaking for some reason, and I have to buy time until a upgrade can be done.

Server is not used for anything except the database.

I want to know the best way to restart MariaDB without creating downtime to keep memory usage in check.

Server specs:

- Dell R7525 / 2 x AMD EPYC 7543
- 128GB RAM / 2x960GB NVMe
- 10Gbit
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Database size 11GB

Comment: How's `systemd` killing your process better than OOM doing the same? Perhaps you will be better off reconfiguring MySQL to use less memory.

Comment: I was thinking in systemd doing a stop then start

Comment: Looks as if you're not the only one looking for such a systemd feature, but it does not seem to exist yet:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/25966

Answer (score 1):

Good grief!  128GB and you are running out of RAM?

You mentioned MariaDB.  The quick fix is to *lower* its `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  That controls a cache, so shrinking it will have only a minor impact on performance.  If the database is only 11GB and you have 128GB of RAM, I would expect changing that setting to 22G would be an excellent starting point.

While that gives you some breathing room, edit the question to list the other apps that are running and their memory usage.

List memory usage of all the products.

Provide MariaDB's `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`; with those we can see if other things are set "too high" or "growing too fast".

Another stopgap:  Increase Ubuntu's swapsize.  That will let the system to continue running even when you exceed the 128GB.  Things will run slower, but at least the evil OOM won't attack.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer a sudden death by OOM over potential crawl-to-a-halt by swap activity; rather having short downtime after which things are back to normal vs. long time of usually increasing slowdown ... choose your poison ...

Comment: @Freedo - Have you changed other things in MariaDB's configuration?

Comment: @Freedo - Remind when that was; I'll check my notes.

Comment: Resent email to vitor...